# how to get the difference of tables in hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have two tables, `A` and `B`, and I just want get all the entries in `A` but not in `B`, and both tables are partitioned by `dt`, so I did the following:

```
1) select A.* from A left join B on A.key=B.key where B.key is null and A.dt=20170101 and B.dt=20170101  -- wrong result

2) select A.* from A left join B on (A.key=B.key and A.dt=20170101 and B.dt=20170101)  -- wrong result

3) select A1.* from (select * from A where dt=20170101) A1 left join (select * from B where dt=2017101) B1 on A1.key=B1.key  -- correct result
```

Why 1) and 2) don't work? I'm so confused...

Comment: When using `left join`, conditions on the *first* table go in the `where` clause.  Conditions in subsequent tables go in the `on` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, seems like you are right, so when use `left join`, I shouldn't put conditions of left table into the `on()` clause but into `where` clause, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) `select A.* from A left join B on A.key=B.key where B.key is null and A.dt=20170101 and B.dt=20170101  -- wrong result`

`where B.key is null and B.dt=20170101` are mutually exclusive if `A.key=B.key`. This basically turned your query into:

```
select A.*
from A
  inner join B 
    on 1=0
```

> 2) `select A.* from A left join B on (A.key=B.key and A.dt=20170101 and B.dt=20170101)` -- wrong result`

`A.dt=20170101` is only applied to the join condition, not the result. This means you would get all of the `dt` for `A`.

> 3) `select A1.* from (select * from A where dt=20170101) A1 left join (select * from B where dt=2017101) B1 on A1.key=B1.key`  -- correct result

These would give you the same result:

```
select a.*
from A
  left join B1
    on A.Key = B.Key
   and B.dt = 20170101
where A.dt = 20170101

select a.*
from A
  left join B
    on A.Key = B.Key
   and A.dt = B.dt
where A.dt = 20170101
```

This is a sql server demo, but it might help illustrate: http://rextester.com/JCZENB83359